# Can we associate K8s serviceAccount with multiple aws IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, k8s-serviceaccount

is it possible in eks to associate  serviceAccount with multiple aws IAM roles? am I allowed to provide multiple arns in service account annotations?
eg

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: Testxxx
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/A-role, arn:aws:iam::987654321:role/B-role
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. You can, however, use the AWS SDKs to assume another role provided the role assigned to the service account includes AssumeRole. See [Assume role with STS using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/example_sts_AssumeRole_section.html) for additional information.